# How to use 2 pageblockTable values in 1 pageBlocktable?

Tags: visualforce, rerender, pageblocktable, actionsupport

In my code, I have 2 pageblockTable with 2 values(apex).
They are displaying data in 2 different tables. First pageblockTable displays the data based on search button after giving input. Second pageBlockTable displays data when the page loads. 
My requirement is to, When I click search button the second pageblockTable old data(default) should disappear and This search data should display in the second pageblockTable.

How to achieve?

**Page:**

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:outputLabel ><B>Search</B></apex:outputLabel><BR/>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Aadhar card Number" for="AdharcardNumberID"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!adharcard}" id="AdharcardNumberId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Last name" for="lastnameId"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!lastname}" id="lastnameId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

            <apex:outputLabel value="Surname" for="SurnameId"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!surname}" id="SurnameId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchRec}" reRender="recMatch, recNotMatch"/>

        <apex:outputPanel id="recMatch">
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem rendered="{!Match}">
                <apex:pageblockTable value="{!searchObj}" var="obj">
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field1}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field2}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field3}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field4}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field5}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field6}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field7}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!obj.field8}"/>
                </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="recNotMatch">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!NoMatch}"> Record Not Found!</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>    


<!--second PageblockTable -->
<apex:pageBlock id="tablePB">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Obj List">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Objects}" var="ob">
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!vict.id}" target="_blank"><apex:outputText value="{!ob.Name}" /></apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>

            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ob.field1}"/>


        </apex:pageBlockTable><BR/>
```

Comment: Use same `list` variable. Initially fetch all the records and when user searches for something, modify the list with searched records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the VF page is having 3 variables that is controlling the visibility of the tables/sections: "NoMatch", "Match" and "SerchMatch". Match is used to show the table which you want to displace without search, NoMatch is used to displace record not found text msg section and SerchMatch is used to displace your search result. One you hit the search button your search method is called and performs the search. Here we are controlling the visibility controlling variables.

Please use the below VF page :

```
<apex:page controller="ShowPageBlock_Class">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Last name" for="lastnameId"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!lastname}" id="lastnameId"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Surname" for="SurnameId"/>
                <apex:inputText value="{!surname}" id="SurnameId"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchRec}" reRender="recMatch, recNotMatch,SerachRcdId,recMatchMrgd"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection> 
    </apex:pageBlock>   

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputPanel id="recNotMatch">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!NoMatch}"> Record Not Found!</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:outputPanel> 

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection >                
            <apex:outputPanel id="SerachRcdId">
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem rendered="{!SerchMatch}">
                    <apex:outputText >Searched Result</apex:outputText>
                    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!searchAccontLst}" var="a">
                         <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!a.Name}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Account Type" value="{!a.type}"/>   
                    </apex:pageblockTable>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>    
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection> 

        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputPanel id="recMatch">
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem rendered="{!Match}">
                    <apex:outputText >Fixed Table</apex:outputText>
                    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!searchObj}" var="a">
                         <apex:column headervalue="Account Name" value="{!a.Name}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Account Type" value="{!a.type}"/>
                         <apex:column headervalue="Industry" value="{!a.industry}"/>    
                    </apex:pageblockTable>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>       
</apex:form>
```

At controller use this:

```
public with sharing class ShowPageBlock_Class {
public String lastname{get;set;}
public String surname{get;set;}
public Boolean NoMatch{get;set;}
public Boolean Match{get;set;}
public List<Account> searchObj{get;set;}
public List<Account> searchAccontLst{get;set;}
public Boolean SerchMatch{get;set;}    


public ShowPageBlock_Class(){
    NoMatch = False;
    Match = True;  
    SerchMatch = False;
    searchObj = new List<Account>();
    searchObj = [select id,name,type,industry from Account];
}

public Void searchRec(){         
    searchAccontLst = new List<Account>();
    searchAccontLst = [select id,name,type,industry from Account where name=:lastname];
    if(searchAccontLst.size()==0){
        NoMatch = True;
        SerchMatch = False; 
        Match = False;          
    }
    else if(searchAccontLst.size()>0){
        NoMatch = False;
        SerchMatch = True;
        Match = False;
    }

}
```

}

Snap :
Default screen before serach :[image]

Snap:
After search : When result found:
[image]

Snap: When record not found
[image]

Comment: Nice to see you here bro :)

Comment: Good to see you too Avijit Da ....

Comment: Hi@Partha Sarathi, Thank you for the answer, If I click search button , That value should displays data in same table, the old table data(default) should disappear? I modified question, Please check.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin - I have modified the code based on ur modified issue comment ... hopefully this will solve ur issue :)

Comment: @Partha Sarathi Mandal,  Thank you so much, It  solved my issue.

Comment: @Partha Sarathi Mandal, Here Fixed Table displaying data below the searched results. So space is coming above the fixed table. How can I avoid space or How can I display search and fixed values at the same location?

Comment: @RavindarAdmin - Put the entire outputPanel (id= recMatch ) i.e. line number 41-51(both inclusive) inside the search pageBlockSection (i.e at line 16). Also please delete the unused pageBlockSection at line no 40 . This will move the content of fixed table inside the search pageBlock . This will definitely solve your problem .

Comment: @ParthaSarathiMandal, Can you please check the url.  It is working with custom controller, I used with standard controller for standard pagination, So with standard pagination It is not working. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178771/rendered-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment270642_178771